# css background-position not working in IE 7 and 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

This page renders great in FF, Chrome, etc.. However in IE 7 and 8, the close "X" which is a background image does not line up.  Any ideas?  I tried to set the `background-position` etc..

The code I have:

```css
.startup-container
{
  width: 455px;
}

.close-startup-home 
{
  background: #c00 url("http://spotlightonhealthyliving.com/btn_closex.png") 0px -8px no-repeat;
  float: right;
  height: 52px;
  width: 60px;
}

.menu-outer
{
  background: #545454;
  -moz-border-radius:5px; 
  border-radius:5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);

}

.menu-inner
{
  background: #3f3f3f;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  -moz-border-radius:5px; 
  border-radius:5px;
}

.startup-box
{
  width:439px;
  line-height:20px;
  text-align: center;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}

.startup-box-inner
{
  width:389px; 
  height:99px;
  padding:20px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="startup-container">
  <div class="close-startup-home"></div>
  <div class="menu-outer startup-box">
    <div class="menu-inner startup-box-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine for me in IE8

Comment: @Pekka IE7 emulated it doesnt but IE8 it works fine. Honestly though does anyone use IE7 anymore?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: [Unfortunately, some still do.](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201010-201110)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a `position: absolute` to your `div` containing the close button and position it according to that.

```css
.startup-container {
    width: 455px;
    position: relative
}

.close-startup-home {
    background: #c00 url("http://spotlightonhealthyliving.com/btn_closex.png") 0px -8px no-repeat;
    float: right;
    height: 52px;
    width: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; 
}
```

Comment: I had to add a z-index: to it, but other than that.. Works great!  You're the best!